# change parameter inside Twitter or Linkedin share

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, regex

I have an anchor where I want to dynamically change a parameter in the href with JavaScript/jQuery.  The business case is I'm calling the bit.ly API on my Rails controller, shortening the <strike>href</strike>substring after url=, and re-inserting the smaller url into the Twitter and LinkedIn share.

I would like to use regular expressions to grab the parameter I want to change, then re-insert the new parameter into the same place in the string.

Here is the original href, but the regular expression I have does not handle the condition where there are multiple ampersands ( sub-parameters ) inside the url= Twitter and Linkedin parameter.

```
var hrefattribute = "https://twitter.com/share?"
    + "url=http://192.168.0.100:3001/hbookmarks/pubhistoryfortoday?currentdate=2015-04-04&username=soysoys&text=open the bookmarks I clicked on 2015-04-04."
```

My JS code to get the url= parameter: ( I got this code from another Stackoverflow article - sorry I can't remember it to link to it  here )

```
var hrefattribute_url = hrefattribute.match(/([\?&])(url=)[^&#]*/)[0];
```

My code to re-insert the updated url= parameter:

```
$('.pubhistoryfortoday_share').prop('href', function(i, action){ 
    return action.replace(/([\?&])(url=)[^&#]*/, '$1$2' + short_url); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the whole `hrefattribute` attribute value, right? Then, you can use the following regex that will match the whole URL up to the attribute value delimiting quote:

`^(.*?)([\?&]url=)[^&#]*(?:[&#][^&#]*)?(&[^'"]*)`

See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/bY8xQ8/1).

```js
var re = /^(.*?)([\?&]url=)[^&#]*(?:[&#][^&#]*)?(&[^'"]*)/; 
var str = 'https://twitter.com/share?url=http://192.168.0.100:3001/hbookmarks/pubhistoryfortoday?currentdate=2015-04-04&username=soysoys&text=open the bookmarks I clicked on 2015-04-04.';
var m;
if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = m[1] + m[2] + 'http://bit.ly/12345678' + m[3]
}
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not a RegEx expert, and it's slowly coming back. But I don't want to shorten the &text= and beyond, only the url= part.  And the regex I have in my initial post, only stops at the first Ampersand in the url= substring, and I need it to go all the way to the end of username=mtm. Thanks.

Comment: So, the problem is that you want to also concatenate the rest of the hrefattribute URL to your shortened URL?

Comment: Yes. I should have put the end state href in the original post. So I want it to look like this: `"https://twitter.com/share?url=http://bit.ly/12345678&text=open the bookmarks I clicked on 2015-04-04."`

Comment: @MarkMilligan: Please check if the updated code will work for you. I used the `hrefattribute` value as input. The end boundary is considered to be `'` or `"`, please change accordingly. If the input string is not enclosed in any quotes, you can use `/^(.*?)([\?&]url=)[^&#]*(&.*)/` regex (see the last capturing group.)

Comment: You are being helpful. Thanks.  Assuming no quotes, I use your last regex, and it still leaves out &username=soysoys.  &username=soysoys is part of the parameter following href=.  So in a way what I want is the regex to not negate the first & that is part of username, but negate the second & that is followed by text=

Comment: Is it better now? I added an optional non-capturing group to consume the first `&` and the parameter after it.